# Display React Component When the Add Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a  React component, and when the "New Section" button is clicked, the component will show up. The problem I am having right now is I want it to be for example, if the button was clicked three times, there will be three sections showing up. But now, when I clicked the "New Section" button, there is a new section showing up and it is in the right place, but I am not able to click it again, and display more sections.

Comment: Change `showSection` from a boolean to an integer and increment it on click. Loop that many times to add the desired # of sections.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close!

You could have a theoretically infinite number of sections so a boolean (true/false) won't cut it for showing more sections. What you need to do is switch that to an integer (1, 2, 3, etc.)

So at the start, you will only have 1 section (I'm assuming) so your state should be `this.state = {sections: 1}`

Change your button to `setState({sections: this.state.sections+1})` so when the new button is clicked, it will add to your sections variable.

And now to get your sections to show properly, you'll want to remove the hardcoded `<Section />` and replace it with a for loop.

```
for (var i=0; i < this.state.sections; i++) {
  <Section />
}
```

If that does it for you then that's that, but if you want to take this a step further and store the values for each section within the sections variable, you'll have to use sections as an array.

`this.state = {sections: [{your_attributes_here: your_values_here}]}`

So anytime the button is clicked, it will have to instead now push to the array a new sections object. This can be achieved simply as

```
let sections = this.state.sections.push({section_info_here});
this.setState({sections: this.state.sections.push({section_info_here})});
```

and generating the html for the sections will now be

```
{this.state.sections.map((section, i) => {
  return <Section sectionData={section}/>
})}
```

This method is only if you need to store data for each individual section. Either method will get you past the problem of not being able to add more than 1 section. Hope this helps!